# Iterating over a table and calling a method in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to iterate over a table of functions, and call each function one by one.
I keep getting the 'attempt to access a field/method NIL value.
Some of them are obvious, but some of them baffle me.

```
 tests={}

function tests.test1()
    print("test1 running\n")
end


function tests.test2()
    print("test2 running\n")
end


function tests.test3()
    print("test3 running\n")
end

print(tests)

-- why is tests.i() or tests:i not working?
for i,x in pairs(tests) do
    print("x is")
    print(x)
    print("i is")
    print(i)

    --tests.i()  -- attempt to call field i a NIL value
    --tests.i(tests) -- ditto
    --tests:i() -- attempt to call method i, a NIl value
    --tests:i(tests) -- ditto 
    tests[i]() -- works!

    --tests.x() -- attempt to call field x, a NIl value
    --tests.x(tests) -- ditto
    --tests:x() -- attempt to call method x, a NIL value
    --tests[x]() -- attempt to call field ? a NIl value
end

--all these work
tests.test1(tests)
tests:test1()

tests.test2(tests)
tests:test2()

tests.test3(tests)
tests:test3()
```

Why is the tests.i() method not working, or tests.i(tests), if it's expecting a 'self' argument, in which case why isn't tests:i() working?
The last bit shows all of them working when called outside the loop, which makes it even more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tests.i()` is syntactic sugar for `tests["i"]()`. `tests:i()` is syntactic sugar for `tests["i"](tests)`.

In your loop ? `for i, x in pairs(tests) do`, `i` is `"test1"`, `"test2"` and `"test3"` in the respective loop cycle. So `tests[i]()` resolves to `tests["test1"]()` and so forth, which is `tests.test1()`

Make sure you understand that `tests.i` is short for `tests["i"]`, not `tests[i]`! So in one case you index `tests` with a string `"i"` while in the second case you'll index it with the value of the variable `i` which in your case is one of the keys of `tests`.

In a loop like yours the values are functions so you can simply call `x` intead of calling `tests[i]` btw.

Answer (score 2):

that inserted-arg will get thrown away when calling `tests:test1()` unless you specify a placeholder for it.

```
tests = {}
function tests.test1( a )  --  you can only use args you've accounted for
    local a = a or ''
    print( 'test1 running', a )
end
```

you can also call `x()` to execute those functions from your loop.

```
-- test i, test i.  1, 2, 3?
for i, x in pairs( tests ) do
    print(  string.format('i is "%s"', i )  )
    print( 'x is', x )

    x()  --  same as calling  tests["i"]()
end

tests:test1()
```

> i is "test1"
> x is function: 0x1420f20
> test1 running
> test1 running    table: 0x1421f10

Comment: you may omit the `local` in `local a = a or ''`. Function parameter `a` is already local to the function's scope